# How to save contacts on windows phone using Windows 8.1 API

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone, contacts, windows-phone-8.1

How do you save contacts to the system phone book not the in app phone book with the windows 8.1 run time API not the silver light 8.1 API?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get/find contacts from the phone book. I think there is no API to save or create new contact in the phone book. Below is the example how you can get contacts in windows 8.1 universal app.

```
public async void FindContacts(string searchText)
    {
        ContactStore contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();

        IReadOnlyList<Contact> contacts = null;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync(searchText);
        }

    }
```